# Trouble using ptTimeSelect with jqGrid edit dialog

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to include a [ptTimeSelect](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html) widget in a jqGrid edit dialog.  The following code snippet is how I am trying to accomplish this.

```
    $('#classTable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#classPager',
    {
        edit: true,
        add: true,
        del: true,
        search: false,
        refresh: false,
        view: true,
        position: "left",
        cloneToTop: false,
        edittitle: "Edit Selected Class",
        addtitle: "Add a Class",
        deltitle: "Delete Selected Class"
    },
    // Options for the edit dialog
    {
        editCaption: "Edit Class",
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        width: 400,
        onInitializeForm: function(form) {
            $("#startTime",form).ptTimeSelect();
            //$("#startTime",form).timepicker();
        }
    },
```

The ptTimeSelect widget posts when I select the field, but I can not interact with it.  It posts behind the the edit dialog and is grayed out.  If I use the timepicker widget (commented above), it posts correctly and works as expected, but I like the ptTimeSelect widget better.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by ptTimeSelect having a low (10) default z-index, and the jqGrid edit dialog having a fairly high one (950).  The solution was to set the z-index for ptTimeSelect much higher.

```
$('#classTable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#classPager',
{
    edit: true,
    add: true,
    del: true,
    search: false,
    refresh: false,
    view: true,
    position: "left",
    cloneToTop: false,
    edittitle: "Edit Selected Class",
    addtitle: "Add a Class",
    deltitle: "Delete Selected Class"
},
// Options for the edit dialog
{
    editCaption: "Edit Class",
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    width: 400,
    onInitializeForm: function(form) {
        $("#startTime",form).ptTimeSelect({zIndex: 975});
        //$("#startTime",form).timepicker();
    }
},
```